# How to create Request and response models in Angular?

Tags: angular

I wonder what is the right way to handle request and response model in Angular. Should we always create 2 different model for get and post operations, or can keywords like ***partial*** fix our problem?

Lets say I want to create user and API asks me those fields:

```
name: string;
username: string;
canRead: boolean;
roleId: string;
```

But when we get user we have also some additional fields. How to handle the difference between those models

Lets say the model when we get user:

```
name: string; 
username: string;
canRead: boolean;
roleName: string;
roleId: string;
```

Comment: I reckon one model should be sufficient as some base properties will probably always exist. The rest you can use as optional properties, ie `roleName?: string` in your case. I don't see the advantage in having two separate models when there are barely any differences.

Comment: Thank you for your help first. I gave this example just for an example but if the difference between two models becomes more should I consider two different model or nullable fields would solve my problem in that case. I don't want to have trouble in the future.

Comment: That would then depend on how big the differences were and how it would affect the rest of your code base. Would it actually improve your code or possibly just complicate things? Those questions depend on your code and your specific use cases.

Answer (score 3):

You can have something like this:

`api-name.model.ts`

```js
interface ApiNameRequest {
    name: string;
    username: string;
    canRead: boolean;
    roleId: string;
}

type ApiNameResponse = ApiNameRequest & {
    roleName: string;
}
```

If the two types differ too much (and one of them doesn't include the second one) then make two types.
You'll have a clean code and you'll know that `roleName` comes only on the response, as a comparison with making one type and having `roleName?` and wondering when will it be available and when it will not.

L.E. Let's suppose your models are:
`request`  `<->` `name, username, canRead, roleId, userId`
`response` `<->` `name, username, canRead, roleId, roleName`

`OPTION 1`: Merge the types

```js
interface ApiNameModel {
    name: string;
    username: string;
    canRead: boolean;
    roleId: string;
    userId?: string; // <- optional, just in Request
    roleName?: string; // <- optional, just in Response
}
```

Now let's say we make the API call:

```js
makeApiCall(url, request: ApiNameModel) {
    code_to_call_the_api
}
...
const request: ApiNameModel = { 
    name: 'a', 
    username: 'a', 
    canRead: true, 
    roleId: 'a'
};

makeApiCall(url, request); // <- you can do this but API will say
                          // you miss userId, so you will get network error
```

`OPTION 2`: Make different types

```js
interface ApiNameRequest {
    name: string;
    username: string;
    canRead: boolean;
    roleId: string;
    userId: string;
}

interface ApiNameResponse {
    name: string;
    username: string;
    canRead: boolean;
    roleId: string;
    roleName: string;
}
```

Now let's say we make the API call:

```js
makeApiCall(url, request: ApiNameRequest) {
    code_to_call_the_api
}
...
const request: ApiNameRequest = { 
    name: 'a', 
    username: 'a', 
    canRead: true, 
    roleId: 'a'
}; // <- you get compile error here saying you miss userId

makeApiCall(url, request); // <- you can't get here until you fix typescript
                          // errors (the build will fail at compile)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I wonder what is the difference between creating two different interfaces for response and request and your solution. You created a type of response and yes it prevents writing the same fields again but is there any different advantages except that. I'm asking this because I really don't know the difference.

Comment: If you go with my solution you won't see the issue. The issue with one model can be seen when you start writing code around it. You will have optional fields that you won't be sure in future where they are desired to come from (request / response). Also, you may have a required field in request that is optional in response. By creating just one model, you have to put that field as optional. The compiler won't stop you to send the request without that optional field, but the response on the request will be "field X is required". (bear in mind that `X` is optional in model, but not in request).

Comment: Again thank you! I wonder that what if I make 

`interface ApiNameRequest {
    name: string;
    username: string;
    canRead: boolean;
    roleId: string;
}`

and for response

`interface ApiNameResponse {
    name: string;
    username: string;
    canRead: boolean;
    roleId: string;
    roleName: string;
}`

Is it the same thing wth what you do ?

Comment: Exactly, it's the same thing. With `&` you merge the types. Also, please see my updated resolution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I was thinking the same perspective as you, I mean I consider separating my models but I have never seen this usage before. Still not sure this is best practice or not.

Comment: You can read about how the things are being done here: https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response

Also, if you write the API too, you may export the Request and Response models and use them from front-end. You need two models on server side, Request to validate the input data and Response to return the data in the specified format. If the API exports these types, there will always be two, one for Request and one for Response. Same should be done on UI.

Comment: I really appreciate your interest and the time you gave. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to working with model yes you create your dto(data transfer object) in your UserRoleDto.ts file or you can create your model in your component.But first option is much better in terms of your architecture.
If you do not work with model you can define your object as "any".

> The Any type is used to represent any JavaScript value. A value of the
> Any type supports the same operations as a value in JavaScript and
> minimal static type checking is performed for operations on Any
> values. Specifically, properties of any name can be accessed through
> an Any value and Any values can be called as functions or constructors
> with any argument list.